# Is the BDE idapi config file being over written by Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi-xe, bde

I am trying to convert a Delphi 3 app to Delphi XE2. It is a BDE based app. But first I have to make some changes to some BDE database entries. This is what I have been doing

1. I use BDE Admin.exe to change the BDE settings.
2. I open Delphi XE2
3. I open a form that contains a TDatabase component
4. I try to change the Database.AliasName using the object inspector
5. The BDE entries that created/modified in step 1 are not listed.
6. I use BDE Admin.exe to check out what is going on
7. All the changes I have made in step one have reverted to what they where

What is going on?!

I'm using Delphi XE2, Win 7, 64 bit

Comment: This sounds like a user rights issue. XE2 is not overwriting it; it's more likely that the IDAPI.CFG file is in a location that can't be written to due to UAC/privileges.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26785399/62576) for some information that might help you.

Comment: To clarify, after dropping down the list of values for a TDatabase.AliasName property on one of the forms in my project using the Delphi XE2's IDE I discover, using the BDE Admin program that the values that were in the IDAPI.CFG file have been changed. It's as if the Delphi IDE is resetting them. Maybe it isn't Delphi itself but something else related to using XE2. The BDE values, BTW,  are reset to values that existed before the edit I did in Step 1.

Comment: Some more information: I tried moving the IDAPI.cfg file to a different location on the C: drive and then went through the steps in my original questing again. This time in Step 6 the BDE says: "IDAPI file not found. Using default values". Also note that after I make chages in Step 1 using the BDE Admin program I save them exit and then open the BDE Admin program again to check if the changes I just made stuck. They are indeed always saved.

Comment: @Ken the BDE Admin program is definitely writing successfully to the IDAPI.CFG file and the the Delphi XE2 IDE is only needing to read from the file.

Comment: I assure you XE2 is not reverting the file to a previous state prior to your edits in BDE Admin. XE2 has absolutely no reason to even open the BDE configuration file until you load your project, at which point it would read it from the disk. I don't know how you tried to move the CFG file, but it's not enough to copy/paste it elsewhere. The post I linked originally explains how to relocate it. Windows by default does not allow you to write to the root of the boot drive (C:\), so you may be experiencing virtual redirection. Check your $USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\VirtualStore folder for the CFG.

Comment: @JonathanElkins: To clarify/improve the question, use the "edit" link to fill in the further information, rather than comments.